# Improve random character output from string

Tags: javascript, algorithm, random

I have a simple for loop that takes a string of characters and spits out 4 random ones, I use this to create game Id that is used in order to synchronize several users together. I feel like my method is not "random enough" and in some case can produce repetitive result even when character sting is that big. There is no need to store created game id's to compare against in order to see if they exist, I would, however, want to figure out a way to perform better random selection of characters from the string.

```
var characters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for( var i=0; i < 4; i++ )
    {
        gameId += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length));
    }
```

*Edit:* perhaps shuffling string before for loop could be a way?

Comment: I like to use current time to help randomize, can you randomize 3 characters and then add 1 depending on the current time of server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple alternative:

```
function generateRandomID() {
   return Math.random().toString(36).slice(-4);
};
```

Obs: just numbers and lower case chars

Answer (score 0):

I usually go with something like this :

```
let length = 4,
    random = (Math.random() * Number.MAX_VALUE).toString(36).substr(0,length);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is as random as you're gonna get, and shuffling the string won't make it "more random". However [this](http://xkcd.com/221/) is potentially a simpler way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your method will work fine. My only question is why are you choosing to use only 4 characters? A longer id might be all you need.